# Hide a Specific Attribute - Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I decided to insert at the the top on the view product some attributes. I want they just appear when they have an information. When is empty i want that the label and information disapear.
The problem is when the current attribute is empty even if it don't have any information it steel appear the label.

Here is my code :

```
<div class="short-information">
                     <a><span class="label"><?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('autor')->getStoreLabel(); ?></span><span class="titles"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getData('autor')); ?></span></a>
                       <a><span class="label"><?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('editorial')->getStoreLabel(); ?></span><span class="titles"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getData('editorial'));?></span></a>
            </div>
```

How Can I make this code work correctly please? To disapear the label when the attibute is empty. 
Just to remenber this is an attribute code that I am inserting in a page and not what is at the bottom of the page view.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify which is the attribute, but you can do it with an if statement like this:

```
<?php if($_product->getResource()->getAttribute('autor')->getStoreLabel()): ?>
                     <a><span class="label"><?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('autor')->getStoreLabel(); ?></span><span class="titles"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getData('autor')); ?></span></a>
<?php endif ?>
```

the same with other attributes.

Comment: Hi Claudiu Thanks a lot for your answer but is not working. The Label still here even if is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for this you need to first check if your attribute has some value or not then you only allow to print label and respective value.

```
<div class="short-information">
   <?php if($this->htmlEscape($_product->getData('autor'))): //checks if author attribute has some value or not ?> 
      <a><span class="label"><?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('autor')->getStoreLabel(); ?></span><span class="titles"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getData('autor')); ?></span></a>
   <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Here i have checked for `author` attribute value, you can do same with other one.